# How do you decorate overridden methods in the child class with decorators applied in methods from the parent class in Python?

Tags: python, methods, decorator

code:

```py
class Parent:
    @classmethod
    def method(cls):
        ...

class Child(Parent):
    def method(cls):
        ...?
```

what do you put in `Parent` to make sure `method` in `Child` is decorated with `classmethod` without explicitly adding `@classmethod` in `Child`?

Comment: You will have to add the decorator to `Child`.

Comment: This seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve that doesn't allow using `@classmethod` in the child class?

Comment: it's possible that somewhere i'd forget about using the decorator on another child class, or i might have to change the decorator to be something else but then i'd have to redo it for all child classes